# Query optimizing

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a table with all sales records (by document/item). 
I need a report with some indicators by item but only for VB Documents (a document type). However I need some indicators such as the maximum quantity per day/item which forces me to another query, but this grouped by day. 
The problem is that I get a very slow query. For a total of 4700000 the query took over 4h.

Is it possible to optimize this query? Probably did not do it the best way...

```
SELECT std.ItemID AS [REF.], SUM(std.Quantity) AS [TOTAL QTY]
, MAX(t1.Qty) AS [MAX QTY BY DAY]
, COUNT(DISTINCT(std.CreateDate)) AS [SALES DAYS]
, DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(std.CreateDate),MAX(std.CreateDate))+1 AS [CALENDAR DAYS]
FROM SaleTransactionDetails std
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CreateDate, ItemID, SUM(Quantity) AS [Qty]
    FROM SaleTransactionDetails
    WHERE TransDocument = 'VB' AND CreateDate > '2012-12-15'
    GROUP BY CreateDate, ItemID) t1 
    ON std.ItemID = t1.ItemID
WHERE std.TransDocument = 'VB' AND std.CreateDate > '2012-12-15'
GROUP BY std.ItemID
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you all!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. (Try codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Depends on indexes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reference the table twice to do this, you can get everything you need from one scan:

```
SELECT  [REF.] = std.ItemID,
        [Total Quantity] = SUM(std.Quantity),
        [Max Qty By Day] = MAX(std.Quantity),
        [Sales Days] = COUNT(std.CreateDate),
        [Calendar Days] = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(std.CreateDate), MAX(std.CreateDate)) + 1
FROM    (   SELECT  std.CreateDate,
                    std.ItemID,
                    Quantity = SUM(std.Quantity)
            FROM    SaleTransactionDetails std
            WHERE   std.TransDocument = 'VB' 
            AND     std.CreateDate > '2012-12-15'
            GROUP BY std.CreateDate, std.ItemID
        ) std
GROUP BY std.ItemID;
```

However, the more important factor in your perfomance will be how the table is indexed. The best way to find out what index is required is run the query with the "Display Actual Execution Plan" option enabled, and then SSMS will suggest an index to improve the query. I would guess that the following [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) will improve performance

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SaleTransactionDetails_ItemID_CreateDate
    ON SaleTransactionDetails (ItemID, CreateDate)
    INCLUDE (Quantity)
    WHERE TransDocument = 'VB';
```

Comment: An index on the `CreateDate` column may help more, depending on the spread of records.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I'd be incredibly surprised if it helped more, the additional sort required on ItemID during the stream aggregate due to ItemID not being in the index will be a massive overhead, regardless of the spread of data.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have set up [a quick SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cd0f/1), if you check the execution plans for the first and second query (the second forces the use of the index on just `createDate`), you will see the additional sort operation is estimated at 78% of the total query cost.

Comment: Thank you very much @GarethD. You gave-me a great help!